# ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to copy data over from a binary file but when trying to instantiate a gameobject, it comes out as "null".

```
static void LoadBuildings(SaveBuilding[] buildings)
    {
        if (buildings.Length == 0)
            return;
        foreach(SaveBuilding b in buildings)
        {
            if(b.type.ToString() == "Farm")
            {
                Farm build = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Farm")) as Farm;
                Debug.Log("Build: " + build);
                build.position.x = b.positionX;
                build.position.y = b.positionY;
                build.level = b.level;
                build.levelText = build.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
            }
        }
    }
```

The debug line shows there is no object and when the next line tries to execute I get an error *ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null*.

I initially had it as *Farm build = Instantiate(build.prefab) as Farm;* as I get an error "Use of unassigned local variable".

I tried adding a prorperty above the if statement "GameObject build", I tried doing Farm build = new Farm() above the if statement also but still get the initial error.

I have a folder titled "Resources" and confirmed a prefab labelled "Farm" is there also.

[image: Resources Folder]

Could it have anything to do with the "static" prefix for the method?

Comment: Have you tried doing `public Trasform farmPrefab;` in the beginning and drag and drop the prefab from the inspector? then on `Instantiate` instead of `Resources.Load("Farm")` you can just put `farmPrefab`.

Comment: Thank you. That does solve the issue, but why didn't my code work? Everything seemed correct and I was calling the Resources.Load() correctly...

Comment: Game Dev doesn't have a canonical dupe for this, but [stack overflow does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a Type when you call Resources Load. Try loading the object in as a gameobject, instantiating it and then calling GetComponent() to retrieve the farm component.

I am guessing that the Farm is a script that you wrote and attached to a GameObject? If so, it is a component so you'd want to load/instantiate the GameObject and get the component

```
GameObject prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Farm") as GameObject;
GameObject farmObject = Instantiate(prefab);
Farm build = farmObject.GetComponent<Farm>();
```

You could combine these into a line or two but it may be easier to debug like this.

Although, remember that Resources.Load is an expensive operation. So avoid using it unless necessary

Comment: You shouldn't need to use both the type specifier `<GameObject>` *and* `as` - the generic `Resources.Load<GameObject>` already returns the type inside the angle brackets, without the need for a cast. Note too that if what you want ultimately is a Farm, it suffices to load & instantiate a `Farm` type (its attached GameObject will come with it)

Answer (score 0):

When using `Resources.Load(string)` you have to supply full path of a file. I'm not the most familiar with it, but I assume <s>the problem with your code is that you put just "Farm" instead of "Farm.prefab" (file extensions do not show up in Unity's UI).</s> Edit: This was a wrong assumption, based on Unity's [Resource.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) documentation, "extensions must be omitted". (Thanks @DMGregory)

Personally I prefer using `public Transform farmPrefab;` in the beginning of the file, then drag and drop the prefab from the inspector, and use `Instantiate(farmPrefab)` from the script. It makes things easier when you want to rename the prefab, or use another one, without editing the code itself.